# Changing the Linux Desktop Environment

Tags: performance, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox, desktop, ubuntu-14.04

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS inside of VirtualBox. Functionally it is great, it is just very slow compared to 12.04. I've seen some posts about changing the desktop to XFCE and other desktops so that the OS runs faster. I like the 12.04 desktop and am wondering if it is possible to use the 12.04 desktop with 14.04. If so, how do I do this?

-Angus

Answer (score 2):

For me, the newest edition of XFCE runs really fast, not slower than any previous version (much faster than default Ubuntu desktop).

To install older version of XFCE, choose version you want and download all the files you need from [here](http://archive.xfce.org/xfce/).

Installation manual I recommend is available on [this site](http://www.howtogeek.com/105413/how-to-compile-and-install-from-source-on-ubuntu/).